# Can I calculate precision from prevalence and misclassification rate?

Tags: bayesian, clinical-trials

If I know $P(D+)=P(disease+)=0.001$, a test is accurate (meaning the test agrees with the truth) 99% of the times, could I calculate the precision $P(D+|T+)=P(disease+|test+)$?

$P(D+|T+)=\frac{P(T+|D+)P(D+)}{P(T+|D+)P(D+)+P(T+|D-)P(D-)}$ by Bayes', but how do I proceed, is more information needed, such as true positive rate and false negative rate?

Comment: Does *"a test is accurate 99% of the time"* mean $P(T+\mid D+)=P(T-\mid D-)=0.99$?  If so, you have enough information

Comment: Sorry, clarifying, accuracy of 99% (or misclassification rate of 1%) means (TN+TP)/(TN+TP+FN+FP)=0.99.

P(T+|D+) = TP/(TP+FN), so I think they are different.

Comment: Then you do not have enough information, though you would with either $P(T+\mid D+)$ or $P(T-\mid D-)$